# Do all mathematical symbols in LaTeX have a meaning?

Tags: soft-question, notation, math-software

I debated whether I should post this on the TeX forum or here. Mathematics seemed more appropriate.

LaTeX has a ridiculous amount of symbols, including countless variations of the integral sign and variations of the logical symbols. So while looking through the compendium of symbols I began to wonder, "I've never seen half (probably more than half) these symbols ever used, what do they even mean?" So I began to wonder if they (the symbols that I have never seen) even had a formal or informal meaning.

So, in summary, do all of the symbols in LaTeX have a meaning, or are their meanings to be defined by the user, who is in need of new notation?

Just going to upload screen cap of symbols,[image]

Comment: It would help if you post an example.

Comment: Most of them have meanings, but not necessarily universal meanings. Some are variations on a theme, such as $\phi$ and $\varphi$ both representing lowercase $\Phi$, and which is user preference most of the time. Other times, there are simply needs to communicate ideas using a variation on a common symbol. The great number of "equals"-style symbols is indicative of the wide range of equivalence relations in various branches of mathematics, for instance. Sometimes, symbols are available but have no commonly-understood use; in that case, it is up to the author to define them *ad hoc.*

Comment: $\doublecap, \ltimes$, etc. I don't know what they mean either.

Comment: There are examples for both - commonly used symbols, using which in a different context will cause confusion, and not so common which may be used in a Humpty-Dumpty style ("When I use a word ... it means just what I choose it to mean — neither more nor less.")

Comment: I'd say - they wouldn't be added if they had no meanings.

Comment: @recursiverecursion I believe doublecap and ltimes are both from the amssymb package rather than the standard distribution. I do not know whether or not symbols from other packages should be included.

Comment: @recursiverecursion well $\ltimes$ looks like a semi direct product in group theory. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semidirect_product

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you can make all the symbols have mathematical meanings, you can just take a symbol you like and assign to it a special meaning. For example let $\daleth_k(n)$ be the number of bijections from a set of size $n$ to the same set of size $n$ which contains no cycles of length less than $k$.

Comment: I just feel like the symbols should be used in an "official" context. Rather than just being used ad hoc

Answer (score 3):

$\LaTeX$ is not only for mathematics. For symbols you have: zodiac signs, cards suits, emoticons, etc... To see the capabilities of $\TeX$ and $\LaTeX$ check this awesome answers: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1319/showcase-of-beautiful-typography-done-in-tex-friends

Comment: Oh my god, the bible...

Comment: I'm well aware, I'm talking about variations of mathematical symbols that I know and brand new symbols included in symbol packages earmarked for mathematics

Answer (score 1):

No. Counterexample:

$\aleph$ has a meaning (initial ordinals), $\beth$ has a meaning (power set cardinals), even $\gimel$ has a meaning (a cardinal function $\gimel(\kappa)=\kappa^{\operatorname{cf}(\kappa)}$).

But $\daleth$ doesn't have a meaning.

(The first four letters of the Hebrew alphabet are $\aleph,\beth,\gimel,\daleth$.)

Comment: I consulted on Latex in the early days. I'm responsible for $\bigcirc$

Comment: Interesting... Who's responsible for $\daleth$?

Comment: see   http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Daleth

Comment: My dad always wanted me to read Bashevis Singer when I was a child, but somehow I never did.